# Scrapy taking 30+ minutes to execute any spiders or scrapy bench

Tags: scrapy

I have a project using `Scrapy 1.0.3`. Everything was running fine, and after no considerable changes, spiders are taking at least 30 minutes to execute. Here are some logs from the prod environment:

```
0:  2015-11-13 12:00:50 INFO    Log opened.
1:  2015-11-13 12:00:50 INFO    [scrapy.log] Scrapy 1.0.3.post6+g2d688cd started
2:  2015-11-13 12:39:26 INFO    [scrapy.utils.log] Scrapy 1.0.3.post6+g2d688cd started (bot: fancy)
3:  2015-11-13 12:39:26 INFO    [scrapy.utils.log] Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto
```

As you can see from the logs, it took ~40 minutes to even start.

From my console if I run `scrapy bench`, `scrapy list` or `scrapy check` I get the same problem.

Does anyone have any ideas?

I've checked this on our dev and prod environment and having the same issue.

I thought it could be code related, but if it's effecting just basic scrapy commands, I am a bit confused as to what this could be.

Normal python scripts execute without issue.

Here is the traceback when cancelling run:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nitrous/code/trendomine/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/home/nitrous/code/trendomine/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 142, in execute
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File "/home/nitrous/code/trendomine/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 209, in __init__
    super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)
  File "/home/nitrous/code/trendomine/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 115, in __init__
    self.spider_loader = _get_spider_loader(settings)
      File "/home/nitrous/code/trendomine/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 296, in _get_spider_loader
    return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
  File "/home/nitrous/code/trendomine/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 30, in from_settings
    return cls(settings)
  File "/home/nitrous/code/trendomine/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 21, in __init__
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "/home/nitrous/code/trendomine/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 71, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/nitrous/code/trendomine/fancy/fancy/spiders/fancy_update_spider.py", line 11, in <module>
    class FancyUpdateSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  File "/home/nitrous/code/trendomine/fancy/fancy/spiders/fancy_update_spider.py", line 28, in FancyUpdateSpider
    pg_r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
  File "/home/nitrous/code/trendomine/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 69, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nitrous/code/trendomine/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nitrous/code/trendomine/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/nitrous/code/trendomine/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nitrous/code/trendomine/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/nitrous/code/trendomine/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 559, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/home/nitrous/code/trendomine/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1051, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 415, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 371, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 476, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
  File "/home/nitrous/code/trendomine/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 179, in recv
    data = self.connection.recv(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nitrous/code/trendomine/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1319, in recv
    result = _lib.SSL_read(self._ssl, buf, bufsiz)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you post your `settings.py` please. Have you tried running the scrapy commands in some other folder, specifically, a folder that isn't part of a scrapy project? If not give it a go and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this was I was performing a huge get request to generate a JSON file to be used as the `start_urls` at the beginning of the script. To resolve this, I wrapped this in a `def start_requests(self)` and instead of using the huge JSON for all requests, I did it after each JSON get request.

New code:

```
import scrapy
from urlparse import urljoin
import re
import json
import requests
import math
from scrapy.conf import settings

from fancy.items import FancyItem

def roundup(x):
  return int(math.ceil(x / 10.0)) * 10

class FancyUpdateSpider(scrapy.Spider):

  name = 'fancy_update'
  allowed_domains = ['foo.com']

  def start_requests(self):
    # Get URLS
    url = 'https://www.foo.com/api/v1/product_urls?q%5Bcompany_in%5D%5B%5D=foo'
    headers = {'X-Api-Key': settings['API_KEY'], 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    # Get initial data
    start_urls_data = json.loads(r.content)
    # Grab the total number of products and round up to nearest 10
    count = roundup(int(r.headers['count']))
    pages = (count / 10) + 1
    for x in start_urls_data:
      yield scrapy.Request(x["link"], dont_filter=True)

    for i in range (2, pages):
      pg_url = 'https://www.foo.com/api/v1/product_urls?q%5Bcompany_in%5D%5B%5D=Fancy&page={0}'.format(i)
      print pg_url
      pg_r = requests.get(pg_url, headers=headers)
      # Add remaining data to the JSON
      additional_start_urls_data = json.loads(pg_r.content)
      for x in additional_start_urls_data:
        yield scrapy.Request(x["link"], dont_filter=True)

  def parse(self, response):
    item = FancyItem()
    item['link'] = response.url
    item['interest'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='frm']/div[@class='figure-button']/a[contains(@class, 'fancyd_list')]/text()").extract_first()
    return item
```